# How to reload gunicorn on server manually?

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

How can I reload gunicorn on an Ubuntu 18.04 server with django 2.1?
I am using 'Nginx + Gunicorn + Supervisor' method. When I am trying

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

I am getting

> 'Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found'

Comment: Please post the supervisor config.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. any fix?